# Problemas Ejecucion AsynkTask

Tags: android, gps, programación-móvil, asynctask

Estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema para un trabajo del colegio, en donde basicamente registro las coordenadas a un servidor.

Tengo un metodo LocationListener, para que cada 5 segundos me envie mis coordenadas al server, hasta ahi todo bien.

El problema es que 3 minutos despues haber iniciado la app, esta deja de enviar mis datos, he realizado varias pruebas y me doy cuenta que el metodo Asynktask no se ejecuta y por ende no me permite enviar mas datos(Pero las coordenadas si se estan generando)

Este es el evento onLocationChanged que envia a cada rato las coordenadas.

```
  @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        enviarCoordenadasBLL.recibirCoordenadas(location);
   }
```

Como podran ver se envia a la capa de BLL, posteriormente a la capa DAL, en donde ejecuto mi AsynkTask

```
public void CoordenadasParaEnviar(Location location){

    EnviarDatosAsynk datos= new EnviarDatosAsynk ();

    datos.execute(lat,lon);

}
```

Posteriormente ejecuto mi AsynkTask y envio los datos, pero como les mencione anteriormente, se ejecuta un par de veces y despues deja de entrar a mi AsynkTask, dentro de mi percepcion siento que el error pueda estar en la cantidad de veces que realizo las instancias (new) porque seria crear instancias cada 5 segundos.

Si tiene alguna sugerencias seria de gran ayuda, ya que no tengo idea de que podra ser el problema.

Comment: Muestra el codigo de como lo llamas cada x segundos

Comment: No tiene nada especial, tan solo utilizo el LocationManager con el parametro

 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000,0,locationListener);

Eso es todo, en este caso esta para cada 3 segundos